# Embeddable Website Viewer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do something kind of like Google's embeddable pdf viewer except I want to be able to embed a website and be able to view that on my website.

Specifically because I have many different teachers and they all use something called Planbook for their assignments, so I want to be able to view all of them at once. Also, I think it would help some other students.

So, does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried to use an <iframe>?

Comment: Well I've tried but how would you use it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. . Unfortunately, this is a very broad question, and not really suited to Stack Overflow - which prefers specific, technical questions (eg "I ran code X and got error Y"). @Dai has suggested you look into using iframes... if you'd like to know how to use them... there's a site I can recommend starting with "G" and ending with "oogle" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to acheive this is to use the HTML iframe. It displays a frame of another webpage, an example usage is `<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`. Also see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) for some more basic info.

Comment: Wow, okay that was simple. Thanks man.